# Computer try to guess user number in C

Tags: c

I made a programme to guess user number.
I miss something in my code, but i dont know what.
If i give input b (bigger) or s (lower), its still give me the same result.
Can you tell me please what should i add to Code to work correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void) 
{
  char answer, input;
  int untere_grenze=1, upper_limit=999, tipp=0, try1=0;

  printf("\n\nThis program tries to guess a number you choose between 1 and 999\n\n");
  do
  {
    try1=0;
    do
    {
      //I think here is my problem

      try1+=1;
      tipp=untere_grenze+(upper_limit-untere_grenze)/2;

      printf("\n%d. try: %d\n", try1, tipp);

      upper_limit=tipp-1;
      untere_grenze=tipp+1;

      //I think here is my problem


      do
      {
        printf("Please enter s (number to be guessed is smaller), b (number to be guessed is larger) or = (guess!):");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        input=toupper(input);
      } while (input!='S' && input!='B' && input!='=');


    } while(input!='=');

    printf("\n\nThe computer guessed your number in %d attempts.\n\n", try1);
    do
    {
      printf("Do you want to run the program again (J/N)?\n\n");
      scanf(" %c", &answer); 
      answer=toupper(answer);
    } while (answer!='J' && answer!='N');
  }  while (answer=='J');

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to take a different action depending on whether your guess is bigger or smaller. Also try doing a binary search, it will be much faster.

Comment: @Pierre Why a binary search? I don't see any ordered array in OPs code.

Comment: @DavidRanieri the positive integers form an ordered array

Comment: @DavidRanieri The "ordered array" is the numbers available to guess from. If the limits are 1 to 100, then start by guess 50. If it's to high then guess 25. Etc. Just like a binary search.

Comment: ok i will try. ty

Comment: @pm100, Someprogrammerdude, I see, thanks!

Comment: @DavidRanieri "Binary search": see Dawn16's code below: guess = low + (up - low) / 2;

Comment: Yes @Pierre, now I understand what you mean, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code logic is horrible, recommend to rewrite, you can reference mine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define LOWER_BOUND     1
#define UPPER_BOUND     999

int main (void)
{
    int low = LOWER_BOUND, up = UPPER_BOUND, guess, try = 0;
    char input;

    printf("Program will guess a number between 1 and 999,"
        "please input s(smaller), b(bigger), or =(equal)\n");

    while (1)
    {
        if (low <= up)
            guess = low + (up - low) / 2;
        else {
            printf("Program terminate, no more guess value\n");
            break;
        }
        ++try;
retry:
        printf("guess %d, please input (s/b/=)\n", guess);
        scanf(" %c", &input);

        if ((input = tolower(input)) == 's') {
            up = guess - 1;
        } else if (input == 'b')
            low = guess + 1;
        else if (input == '=')
            break;
        else
            goto retry;
    }

    printf("Summary: Trial: %d\n", try);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your program doing anything with the input.
You should guess lower or higher in the next iteration based on the input.